# Python placeholder

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to read tables from MySQL into python using pymysql... while declaring the schema statement, I am unable to place a placeholder. Here is the example code:

```
schema = "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s'"%(,db_name)
```

I tried this swell..

```
schema = "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s'"%db_name
```

I want to give a name stored in db_name as TABLE_SCHEMA, but it is throwing error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
schema = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%%' and TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s'"%(db_name)
```

Note, however, that you should prefer f-strings (Python 3.6+) or str.format() over the % method.